# Android - How to use Facebook deferred deep linking feature for new installs and to test the same before publishing Android play store?

Tags: android, android-studio, facebook, deep-linking

Followed all the steps given in following link:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/deep-linking

But I'm not able to test deferred deeplink as app is not available on play store.

I followed these steps to test deferred deep link:

Visit https://developers.facebook.com/tools/app-ads-helper

Select your app and hit 'Submit'.

At the bottom you will find 'Deep Link Tester' under Developer Tools. Hit 'Test Deep Link' and in the dialog you can enter your deep link to test.

If you want to verify deferred links then check 'Send Deferred' in the dialog.

Then I am getting error saying:

> The link has been queued and is pending you doing a first app launch on your device. This means you need to delete the app, then re-install and open your app. Please first verify your app can handle deferred deep linking by checking the iOS and Android setup information located above.

[image]